# Book return flight, but after another round trip

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I am currently in the US. I plan on leaving back to my home country (UK) on October 18th, but I haven't booked it yet.

I did already book a trip back to the US with a relative for a week in November.

As we know, it's expensive to book a one way flight. Because I will likely come back to the US again next year (I have friends there and also go to conferences) can I book a return flight to leave on the 18th and come back next year?

For example:

- 18th October 2019 US -> Home (Ticket 1)
- 5th November 2019 Home -> US (Ticket 2)
- 12th November 2019 US -> Home (Ticket 2)
- Some time in March 2020 Home -> US (Ticket 1)

I wouldn't cancel the ticket (2) after I fly home. It's likely I would really use the return segment to come back and then have another one-way ticket to return back home in March.

Is this possible?
Thanks